# Update of UI relevant items of ObservableRangeCollection not updated

Tags: maui

In [#20821](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20821) I described a, for me weird, behavior in my App which used to work before in .NET 7 and updated the UI successfully when the `ObservableRangeCollection` was updated in a Calculate method in my ViewModel.

Now, as it is shown in the issue I wrote, it doesn’t update the value of a bound `CollectionView`. When I switch the View and back it updates the values, but starts to toggle as can be seen in the animation.

Today, I was looking again at the Code and searching for something that might noch be a MAUI Bug in the [example project](https://github.com/MAUIoxo/DataBindingCorrupted_2081).

Well, what I am not sure about is the [Tab1ViewModel](https://github.com/MAUIoxo/DataBindingCorrupted_2081/blob/main/DataBindingCorruptedExample/ViewModels/TabView1ViewModel.cs) and the async Tasks all around during updates of the `SelectedStores` collection. As described in the Bug from the link above and when you set the Breakpoints correspondingly, the elements are updated underneath, but the UI is not showing them at first.

Am I really doing the updates on the `ObservableRangeCollection` with Cleaning of the elements correctly regarding Threads? I came across a Thread and read that all Updates have to be done on the UI Thread so that Notifications are done correctly? Question is with the use of all the `async Tasks` all around, how would I do that? How should this be done - are there recommendations or best practices?

Fact is, right now, I am even not sure, if it is my fault and not of the .NET 7 to .NET 8 switch.

Are there any recommendations or things I could try to improve my Code?

Here is an animation that demonstrates what I mean:

[image]

======= Update with Code ========

**ViewModel** with the `SelectedStoreItems` `ObservableRangeCollection` which’s elements get removed on the way and re-integrated on the way. This is also done as it is possible to add new elements or some of them could be deleted, some might stay in the collection:

```cs
public partial class TabView1ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableRangeCollection<StoreSelection> SelectedStoreItems { get; set; }

    
    public AsyncCommand RefreshDatabaseCommand { get; }
    public AsyncCommand CalculateStoreProfitsCommand { get; }
    public AsyncCommand SaveStoreCommand { get; }
    public AsyncCommand DisplayBottomSheetCommand { get; }
    public AsyncCommand<StoreSelection> ExcludeFromStoreSelectionCommand { get; }
    public AsyncCommand DragAndDropEndedCommand { get; }



    public TabView1ViewModel()
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<RefreshDataBaseMessage>(this, HandleDatabaseChangedMessage);
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<UpdateSelectedStoreItemsMessage>(this, HandleUpdateSelectedStoreItemsMessage);


        SelectedStoreItems = new ObservableRangeCollection<StoreSelection>();
        
        DisplayBottomSheetCommand = new AsyncCommand(DisplayBottomSheetCommandHandler);
        CalculateStoreProfitsCommand = new AsyncCommand(CalculateStoreProfitsCommandHandler);
        SaveStoreCommand = new AsyncCommand(SaveStoreCommandHandler);
        ExcludeFromStoreSelectionCommand = new AsyncCommand<StoreSelection>(ExcludeFromStoreSelectionCommandHandler);
        DragAndDropEndedCommand = new AsyncCommand(DragAndDropEndedCommandHandler);

        RefreshDatabaseCommand = new AsyncCommand(RefreshDatabaseCommandHandler);
        RefreshDatabaseCommand.ExecuteAsync();

        GC.Collect();
    }

    private List<Store> GetSomeStoreExamples()
    {
        var store1 = new Store
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Apple Store",
            Street = "Apple Store Street",
            Manager = 1,
            SalesPerson = 10.0,
            Clerk = 5
        };

        var store2 = new Store
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Banana Store",
            Street = "Banana Store Street",
            Manager = 2,
            SalesPerson = 20.0,
            Clerk = 12.0
        };



        var storeSelection1 = new StoreSelection()
        {
            StoreItem = store1,
            SortOrderIndex = 1,
            IsSelected = true,
            Min = 1,
            Max = 5,
            OptimalProfit = 3
        };

        var storeSelection2 = new StoreSelection()
        {
            StoreItem = store2,
            SortOrderIndex = 2,
            IsSelected = true,
            Min = 0,
            Max = 2,
            OptimalProfit = 1
        };

        store1.StoreSelections.Add(storeSelection1);
        store2.StoreSelections.Add(storeSelection2);

        return new List<Store> { store1, store2 };
    }



    #region Message Command Handlers

    private async void HandleDatabaseChangedMessage(object recipient, RefreshDataBaseMessage refreshDatabaseMessage)
    {
        await RefreshDatabaseCommandHandler();
    }

    private async void HandleUpdateSelectedStoreItemsMessage(object recipient, UpdateSelectedStoreItemsMessage updateSelectedStoreItemsMessage)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        
        ResetMinMaxAndOptimalProfitForNewSelections();
        
        await CollectSelectedStoreItems();

        GC.Collect();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Command Handler

    private Task DisplayBottomSheetCommandHandler()
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new DisplayBottomSheetMessage(true));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task CalculateStoreProfitsCommandHandler()
    {
        // ... do some calculations here
        CalculateReachedProfits(SelectedStoreItems);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedStoreItems));

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void CalculateReachedProfits(IEnumerable<StoreSelection> selectedStores)
    {
        foreach (var selectedStore in selectedStores)
        {
            selectedStore.OptimalProfit = 10;
        }            
    }


    private async Task RefreshDatabaseCommandHandler()
    {
        GroupStoreItemsApplyingSearchFilter();

        await CollectSelectedStoreItems();

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task SaveStoreCommandHandler()
    {
        // ... save store and selected stores in the DB

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task ExcludeFromStoreSelectionCommandHandler(StoreSelection storeItemToExclude)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (var group in GroupedStoreItems)
            {
                // Find the item with matching Store Id in the current group
                var itemToExclude = group.FirstOrDefault(item => item.StoreItem.Id == storeItemToExclude.StoreItem.Id);

                if (itemToExclude != null)
                {
                    itemToExclude.IsSelected = false;
                }
            }
        });

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupedStoreItems));

        HandleUpdateSelectedStoreItemsMessage(this, new UpdateSelectedStoreItemsMessage(true));

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task DragAndDropEndedCommandHandler()
    {
        UpdateSortOrderIndices(SelectedStoreItems);

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Search Filter

    private string _searchText;
    public string SearchText
    {
        get => _searchText;
        set
        {
            if (_searchText != value)
            {
                _searchText = value;

                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchText));
                GroupStoreItemsApplyingSearchFilter();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Grouping of StoreItems

    private ObservableRangeCollection<GroupedStoreSelectionItemList> _groupedStoreItems { get; set; }
    public ObservableRangeCollection<GroupedStoreSelectionItemList> GroupedStoreItems
    {
        get => _groupedStoreItems != null ? _groupedStoreItems : _groupedStoreItems = new ObservableRangeCollection<GroupedStoreSelectionItemList>();
        set
        {
            if (_groupedStoreItems != value)
            {
                _groupedStoreItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupedStoreItems));
            }
        }
    }

    private void GroupStoreItemsApplyingSearchFilter()
    {   
        var storeItems = GetSomeStoreExamples();

        var query = storeItems
            .Where(storeItem => string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText) || storeItem.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower()))
            .OrderBy(storeItem => storeItem.Name)
            .GroupBy(storeItem => storeItem.Name.First().ToString(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            .OrderBy(group => group.Key, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            .Select(group =>
            {
                // Create a list of StoreSelections by mapping each StoreItem in the group to a new StoreSelection instance
                var storeSelections = group.Select(storeItem =>
                {
                    var selectedStoreItem = SelectedStoreItems.FirstOrDefault(selectedItem => selectedItem.StoreItem.Id == storeItem.Id);

                    if (selectedStoreItem != null)
                    {
                        return selectedStoreItem;
                    }

                    return new StoreSelection
                    {
                        Id = selectedStoreItem?.Id ?? 0,
                        StoreId = storeItem?.Id ?? 0,
                        StoreItem = storeItem,
                        IsSelected = selectedStoreItem != null && selectedStoreItem.IsSelected,
                        Min = selectedStoreItem?.Min ?? 0,
                        Max = selectedStoreItem?.Max ?? 0,
                        OptimalProfit = selectedStoreItem?.OptimalProfit ?? 0,
                        SortOrderIndex = selectedStoreItem?.SortOrderIndex ?? -1,
                    };

                }).ToList();

                // Create a GroupedStoreSelectionItemList using the key and the list of StoreSelections
                return new GroupedStoreSelectionItemList(group.Key, storeSelections);
            });

        GroupedStoreItems.Clear();
        GroupedStoreItems.AddRange(query);
        
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupedStoreItems));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Selected StoreItems

    private async Task CollectSelectedStoreItems()
    {
        // Retrieve the selected StoreItems from GroupedStoreItems and order them based on their SortOrderIndex
        var selectedStoreItems = GroupedStoreItems
            .SelectMany(groupedStoreSelectionItem => groupedStoreSelectionItem)
            .Where(storeSelectionItem => storeSelectionItem != null && storeSelectionItem.IsSelected == true)
            .OrderBy(storeSelectionItem => storeSelectionItem.SortOrderIndex == -1 ? int.MaxValue : storeSelectionItem.SortOrderIndex)
            .ToList();

        // Set IsSelected to true for all selectedStoreItems
        selectedStoreItems.ForEach(item => item.IsSelected = true);

        // Set IsSelected to false for all items not in selectedStoreItems
        foreach (var groupedItem in GroupedStoreItems.SelectMany(group => group))
        {
            if (!selectedStoreItems.Any(item => item.StoreItem.Id == groupedItem.StoreItem.Id))
            {
                groupedItem.IsSelected = false;
            }
        }

        UpdateSortOrderIndices(selectedStoreItems);

        GC.Collect();

        //SelectedStoreItems.Clear();

        int count = SelectedStoreItems.Count;
        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            SelectedStoreItems.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        SelectedStoreItems.AddRange(selectedStoreItems);

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedStoreItems));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupedStoreItems));

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resets the Min, Max, Optimal Profit values for newly selected StoreSelection items in the grouped collection.
    /// </summary>
    private async void ResetMinMaxAndOptimalProfitForNewSelections()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Retrieve the selected StoreItems
            var selectedStoreItems = GroupedStoreItems
                .SelectMany(group => group)
                .Where(storeSelectionItem => storeSelectionItem.IsSelected)
                .ToList();

            var newlySelectedItems = selectedStoreItems.Where(newItem => !SelectedStoreItems.Any(existingItem => existingItem.StoreItem?.Id == newItem.StoreItem?.Id)).ToList();


            // Reset Min, Max, and Optimal Profit values for the newly selected items
            foreach (var newlySelectedItem in newlySelectedItems)
            {
                newlySelectedItem.Min = 0;
                newlySelectedItem.Max = 0;
                newlySelectedItem.OptimalProfit = 0;
            }
        });
        
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupedStoreItems));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the SortOrderIndex for each element in the collection based on its position in the list starting at index 1.
    /// Updates the corresponding SortOrderIndex in the GroupedStoreItems collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selectedStoreItems">The IEnumerable of selected StoreItems used to determine the SortOrderIndex.</param>
    private async void UpdateSortOrderIndices(IEnumerable<StoreSelection> selectedStoreItems)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int index = 1;

            // Update SortOrderIndex for selectedStoreItems
            foreach (var selectedStoreItem in selectedStoreItems)
            {
                selectedStoreItem.SortOrderIndex = index;
                index++;
            }

            // Update SortOrderIndex for GroupedStoreItems based on selectedStoreItems
            foreach (var group in GroupedStoreItems.ToList())
            {
                foreach (var storeSelectionItem in group)
                {
                    // Check if the item is in the selectedStoreItems list
                    var correspondingItem = selectedStoreItems.FirstOrDefault(selectedStoreItem => selectedStoreItem.StoreId == storeSelectionItem.StoreId);

                    // Update SortOrderIndex for the item based on its presence in the selectedStoreItems list
                    storeSelectionItem.SortOrderIndex = correspondingItem != null ? correspondingItem.SortOrderIndex : -1;
                }
            }
        });

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupedStoreItems));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Eventing

    event PropertyChangedEventHandler? INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add => weakEventManager.AddEventHandler(value);
        remove => weakEventManager.RemoveEventHandler(value);
    }

    private readonly Microsoft.Maui.WeakEventManager weakEventManager = new();

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] in string propertyName = "") => weakEventManager.HandleEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName), nameof(INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged));

    #endregion
}
```

**DataTemplate** in the ResourceDictionary:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="VerticalItemTemplate" x:DataType="{x:Type databaseModels:StoreSelection}">
    <sho:DraggableViewCell>
        <views:StoreSelectionItemView />
    </sho:DraggableViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

**CollectionView** and integration of its `ContentView`:

```xml
<!-- Collection to display the Selected Items -->
<Grid RowDefinitions="*" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" HeightRequest="500">

    <sho:CollectionView CollectionPadding="10, 10, 10, 10"
                        EnableDragAndDrop="True"
                        DragAndDropDirection="VerticalOnly"
                        DragAndDropTrigger="LongTap"
                        DragAndDropEndedCommand="{Binding DragAndDropEndedCommand}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedStoreItems, Mode=OneWay}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VerticalItemTemplate}"
                        MinimumHeightRequest="250"
                        AnimateScroll="True"
                        DisableScroll="False"
                        CollectionLayout="Vertical"
                        x:Name="Tab1ViewCollectionView">

        <sho:CollectionView.ItemHeight>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                <On Platform="iOS">85</On>
                <On Platform="Android">80</On>
            </OnPlatform>
        </sho:CollectionView.ItemHeight>

    </sho:CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

======= Getting more Concrete ========

1. After clicking the **Calculate**-Button the corresponding `CalculateStoreProfitsCommandHandler` is reached to call `CalculateReachedProfits` which just sets the `OptimalProfit`property of all selected stores to `selectedStore.OptimalProfit = 10;`
2. In the Animation you the breakpoints in the `CalculateStoreProfitsCommandHandler` **before** `CalculateReachedProfits(SelectedStoreItems);` which sets the above value. There Debugger shows `OptimalProfit = 0;`
3. What the Animation shows next is **after** the call of `CalculateReachedProfits(SelectedStoreItems);` which correctly shows that each value of `SelectedStoreItems` is update to `selectedStore.OptimalProfit = 10;`
4. As I have an `ObservableRangeCollection<StoreSelection>` I already would expect here to see the update on the UI. But, I also called `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedStoreItems));` in `CalculateStoreProfitsCommandHandler` to make sure it really gets updated. **But, the Animation also shows, the UI is not updated**
5. After that it gets weird, as when I click on the second Tab in the Animation and back to the first Tab, the UI shows the correct value for `OptimalProfit = 10`. When I switch Tabs back and forth more often these values toggle from `OptimalProfit = 10` to `OptimalProfit = 0` back and forth.
6. What happens when I click on the second Tab is that a `WeakReferenceMessenger` will send a message to this `ViewModel` to update the database and we get to `HandleDatabaseChangedMessage(...)` to call `await RefreshDatabaseCommandHandler();`
7. In `CollectSelectedStoreItems()` we will build up the `SelectedStoreItems` from its master `ObservableRangeCollection` named `GroupedStoreItems` store items. This can be considered as the "Database" for the rest. This keeps all possible values from which we can select a couple of them and which can finally be found in the `SelectedStoreItems`. `GroupedStoreItems` as it works with references contains also the update values for `OptimalProfit` underneath. The `SelectedStoreItems` are cleared (or better deleted one by one as there was a Memory Problem when using method `Clear()` and obviously weak references for notifications got not deleted. That's the reason why I delete it one by one which did help to unsubscribe the eventing references and memory did not increase. But this is just a side notice. The idea why `SelectedStoreItems` is cleared and built up again is that users also can select a different set of `SelectedStoreItems` and remove and add them. So, at this point it is cleared and built up again with all the selected elements from `GroupedStoreItems`.

What I am not sure about is why the UI does not get updated? And additionally if all these async method calls with Task all around are the problem maker in this context. Or in other words, am I doing it wrong and could improve it so that the Updates of the UI can be seen?

======= StoreSelection with INotifyPropertyChanged ========

```cs
public class StoreSelection : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Private Variables

    private SavedStore _savedStore;
    private Store _storeItem;

    #endregion


    [Key]                                                   // Primary Key will already be indexed in a Table
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    #region SavedStoreItem

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("SavedStore")]
    public int SavedStoreId { get; set; }
    public virtual SavedStore SavedStoreItem
    {
        get => _savedStore;
        set
        {
            if (_savedStore != value)
            {
                _savedStore = value;
                if (_savedStore != null)
                {
                    SavedStoreId = _savedStore.Id;
                }

                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SavedStoreItem));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region StoreItem

    [Column(Order = 3)]
    [ForeignKey("Store")]
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public virtual Store StoreItem
    {
        get => _storeItem;
        set
        {
            if (_storeItem != value)
            {
                _storeItem = value;
                if (_storeItem != null)
                {
                    StoreId = _storeItem.Id;
                }

                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(StoreItem));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region SortOrderIndex

    [Column(Order = 4)]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int SortOrderIndex { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region IsSelected

    private bool _isSelected = false;

    [NotMapped]
    [Column(Order = 5)]
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected != value)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Min Profit

    private int _min = 0;

    [Column(Order = 6)]
    public int Min
    {
        get => _min;
        set
        {
            _min = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsValid));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Max Profit

    private int _max = 0;

    [Column(Order = 7)]
    public int Max
    {
        get => _max;
        set
        {
            _max = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsValid));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Optimal Profit

    private int _optimalProfit = 0;

    [Column(Order = 8)]
    public int OptimalProfit
    {
        get => _optimalProfit;
        set
        {
            _optimalProfit = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(OptimalProfit));
        }
    }

    #endregion        

    #region IsValid

    [NotMapped]
    [Column(Order = 9)]
    public bool IsValid { get => Max >= Min; }

    #endregion



    #region Eventing

    private readonly WeakEvent<PropertyChangedEventHandler> _propertyChangedEvent = new WeakEvent<PropertyChangedEventHandler>();

    event PropertyChangedEventHandler? INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add => _propertyChangedEvent.AddHandler(value);
        remove => _propertyChangedEvent.RemoveHandler(value);
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        _propertyChangedEvent.RaiseEvent(handler => handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)));
    }

    #endregion                
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the body, not as a link to an offsite resource

Comment: Okay, I updated the relevant Code of the `ViewModel`. Question is, if I am doing things wrong here and if all the asyncs destroy the updates on the UI Thread or if this even is mandatory. Maybe the animated give in the first link to the issue I wrote helps to see what I mean

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you are changing?  Ie, “when I add a new item to ListA in MethodB I expect to see it appear in ListViewC but it does not”

Comment: I updated more details in my original question and also tried to make it more visual in the Animation. Added also more explanation. Hope it helps. Otherwise just let me know what is needed

Comment: Why do you call `GC.Collect()` in the constructor of your ViewModel? Ideally, you shouldn't be doing any manual calls to the garbage collector.

Comment: Admittedly this might appear weird, but when I was running into the memory issues while I was using `Clear()` on the `ObservableRangeCollection` and I started to experiment why and found out that event notifications increased, I was using `RemoveAt(i)` to delete the items which helped, but finally only in combination with the `GC.Collect()` calls below. In the constructor this is just to make sure we keep it clean from the beginning. This one, I could probably remove now! Thanks for the hint

Comment: As I understand, you select a value from tab 1 and want to apply this value in tab2. I use "MessagingCenter" in xamarin forms to do this. You can try this if you want to do update a value from another page.

Comment: Is the OptimalProfit property Observable?

Comment: Yes it is. But, it is in a DLL that is a non MAUI DLL - that has something to do with the EF-Framework implemented in this DLL. What I am asking myself while playing around with the sources is when I remove async from methods. I can get a result when I hit calculate and remove the async from the calculate method. But the problem is, when I hit it a 2nd time it also toggles when the Refresh of the Database is triggered again. But in all of the methods I can see the right values in debugger. Is there anything regarding MainUI-Thread and async I am missing? (Notification from async methods to UI)

Comment: I still do not get how the values can toggle when I see the right values in the Debugger and are different from 0. How could it get 0 then? And the thing is the more async there is the more it appears to me with this unhandled effects. I tried also to use explicit UI Thread for updates on the `SelectedStoreItems ` which is cleared and re-added with the right items that are selected. Are UI-Threads and other Threads mixed by async and is there an idea how I can prevent that?

Comment: @Jason - thanks for asking if the property is Observable. As I mentioned these classes were in a .NET 8 Core DLL not a .NET MAUI DLL. I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` which used to work in .NET 7. Now, I think it got broken somehow. As you mentioned it yesterday, I thought about what you said and came to the conclusion that this really must have something to do with the notifications from these data objects when they change. I gave the `ObservableObject` from the `MVVM Community Toolkit` a try and implemented it. Seems like it is back to work with this change. No toggling anymore, so far